# Procedure in sql to insert 10 records into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, recursive-query

I've tried this stored procedure to insert into ledger table 10 records with random data but it doesn't work, after executing successfully it doesn't insert anything in the table. what i did wrong??? can anybody help me....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FillLedger  
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @c INT = 1,
       @itemNo int = floor(rand()*11),
       @quantity  int = floor(rand()*50) + 50,
       @date  datetime = '2015-01-01'
While @c > 11 
  BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO dbo.LEDGER
         (                    
           item_id           ,
           QTY               ,
           PostingDate                 
         ) 
    VALUES 
         ( 
           @itemNo,
           @quantity,
           @date
         ) 
         Set @c = @c + 1 ;  
   END
END 
GO
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not very helpful.  What is the issue?

Comment: it doesn't insert anything in the table. but when executing it doesn't show any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want your `WHERE` clause to be:

```
While @c < 11
```

Your code might have other errors as well.

You do realize that this inserts the *same* 10 rows into the table.  You initialize the values outside the `WHERE` body, so the column values never change.

Comment: This didn't fix your problem?  You originally accepted this answer.

Comment: you are right my problem doesn't solved, I realized that later but couldn't do what to do.

Comment: my procedure work successfully but doesn't insert anything in the table, after the answer above it has inserted 10 records with the same values, so i really don't know what to do, but i am still searching for the answer.

Comment: @Aalaamohammad . . . Ask a *new* question.  Describe what you want to do in words.  Provide sample data as an example of what you want to insert.  You can show your code, but the question should be phrased in words, not code.

Comment: OK I will, thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a recursive query instead of a loop. Assuming SQL Server:

```
with cte as (
    select @itemno as item_id, @quantity as qty, @date as postingdate, 1 as c
    union all
    select item_id, qty, postingdate, c + 1 from cte where c < 10
)
insert into dbo.ledger(item_id, qty, postingdate)
select tem_id, qty, postingdate from cte
```

---

Edit: if you want 10 records with a random item id and quantity, then you need to move the random assignment within the subquery:

```
with cte as (
    select floor(rand()*11) as item_id, floor(rand()*50) + 50 as qty, @date as postingdate, 1 as c
    union all
    select floor(rand()*11), floor(rand()*50) + 50, postingdate, c + 1 from cte where c < 10
)
insert into dbo.ledger(item_id, qty, postingdate)
select tem_id, qty, postingdate from cte
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works now.

Comment: I am sorry, after look with concentrate i realized that it inserted the same record 10 times.

Comment: @Aalaamohammad: I think I see what you mean. See my edit

Comment: Thank for your time, but  this repeated the second record so i have one record different but 9 similar records.